# Não estou conseguido registrar dados no banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, persistência

Sou iniciante em java e estou com o seguinte problema. Na tela de cadastro de estado, tenho um selectOneMenu de país, e dois campos para nome e sigla.

Quando vou salvar no banco de dados recebo o seguinte erro:

Console:

```
2018-05-24 01:16:53,033 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Column 'pais_id' cannot be null
```

Seguem meus códigos:

CadastroEstado.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">#{cadastroEstadoBean.editando ? 'Edição de estado' : 'Novo estado'}</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="breadcrumb">
        <li>Pages</li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li><p:link outcome="/estados/cadastroEstado">Novo estado</p:link></li>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event listener="#{cadastroEstadoBean.inicializar()}" type="preRenderView" />
            <o:viewParam name="estado" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.estado}" />
        </f:metadata>

        <h:form>
            <h1>#{cadastroEstadoBean.editando ? 'Edição de estado' : 'Novo estado'}</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 10px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/estados/cadastroEstado" />
                    <p:commandButton id="botaoSalvar" value="Salvar" action="#{cadastroEstadoBean.salvar()}" update="@form" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>

                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisar" outcome="/estados/pesquisaEstado" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

                <p:outputLabel value="País" for="pais"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="pais" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.pais}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o país"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.listaPaises}" var="pais"
                        itemValue="#{pais}" itemLabel="#{pais.nome}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome" />
                <p:inputText id="nome" size="45" maxlength="50" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.estado.nome}" />

                <p:outputLabel for="sigla" value="Sigla" />
                <p:inputText id="sigla" size="10" maxlength="10" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.estado.sigla}" />

            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Estado

```
package com.damasystem.dama.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "estado")
public class Estado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;
    private Pais pais;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2)
    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    public Pais getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(Pais pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Estado other = (Estado) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Pais

```
package com.damasystem.dama.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pais")
public class Pais implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;
    private List<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 3)
    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Estado> getEstados() {
        return estados;
    }

    public void setEstados(List<Estado> estados) {
        this.estados = estados;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pais other = (Pais) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

CadastroEstadoBean

```
package com.damasystem.dama.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.damasystem.dama.model.Estado;
import com.damasystem.dama.model.Pais;
import com.damasystem.dama.repository.Paises;
import com.damasystem.dama.service.CadastroEstadoService;
import com.damasystem.dama.util.jsf.FacesUtil;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroEstadoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Estado estado;

    private Pais pais;
    private Pais paisSelecionado;

    @Inject
    private CadastroEstadoService cadastroEstadoService;

    @Inject
    private Paises repositorioPaises;

    private List<Pais> listaPaises;

    public CadastroEstadoBean() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void inicializar() {
        if (this.estado == null) {
            limpar();
        }
        listaPaises = repositorioPaises.paises();
    }

    private void limpar() {
        estado = new Estado();
        pais = new Pais();
        listaPaises = null;

    }

    public boolean isEditando() {
        return this.estado.getId() != null;
    }

    public void salvar() {
        this.estado = cadastroEstadoService.salvar(this.estado);
        limpar();

        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Estado salvo com sucesso.");
    }

    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Pais getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(Pais pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public Pais getPaisSelecionado() {
        return paisSelecionado;
    }

    public void setPaisSelecionado(Pais paisSelecionado) {
        this.paisSelecionado = paisSelecionado;
    }

    public List<Pais> getListaPaises() {
        return listaPaises;
    }

}
```

CadastroEstadoService

```
package com.damasystem.dama.service;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.damasystem.dama.model.Estado;
import com.damasystem.dama.repository.Estados;
import com.damasystem.dama.util.jpa.Transactional;

public class CadastroEstadoService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Estados estados;

    @Transactional
    public Estado salvar(Estado estado) {
        Estado estadoExistente = estados.porNome(estado.getNome());

        if(estadoExistente != null && !estadoExistente.equals(estado)) {
            throw new NegocioException("Já existe um estado com o nome informado.");
        }

        return estados.guardar(estado);
    }

}
```

Estados (repository)

```
package com.damasystem.dama.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import com.damasystem.dama.model.Estado;

public class Estados implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Estado guardar(Estado estado) {
        return estado = manager.merge(estado);
    }

    public Estado porNome(String nome) {
        try {
            return manager.createQuery("from Estado where upper(nome) = :nome", Estado.class)
                    .setParameter("nome", nome.toUpperCase())
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Estado porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(Estado.class, id);
    }

}
```

EstadoConverter

```
package com.damasystem.dama.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import com.damasystem.dama.model.Estado;
import com.damasystem.dama.repository.Estados;

@FacesConverter(forClass = Estado.class)
public class EstadoConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private Estados estados;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Estado retorno = null;

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            Long id = new Long(value);
            retorno = estados.porId(id);
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Estado estado = (Estado) value;
            return estado.getId() == null ? null : estado.getId().toString();
        }

        return "";
    }


}
```

Tabela pais criada através do "create"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela estado criada através do "create" 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: `Column 'pais_id' cannot be nul` ou seja, o valor está indo como nulo e ele não pode ser salvo como tal em sua tabela

Comment: Com certeza Woton. O erro ocorre por isso. O que não estou entendendo é porque está retornando nulo. Acho que o mapeamento está correto,  mas não consigo achar porque está indo nulo.

Comment: Ao selecionar o estado no selectonemenu, verifica se está vindo com id preenchido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somente para registrar que acabei de encontrar que o erro no arquivo cadastroEstado.xhtml, no selectOneMenu.

Estava:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="pais" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.pais}" >
```

Deveria estar:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="pais" value="#{cadastroEstadoBean.estado.pais}" >
```

Answer (score 2):

O que acho que esta acontecendo em seu código é que você deve ter gerado uma tabela antes com dados diferentes, o porque disso é que ao analisar o erro ele retorna:

```
Column 'pais_id' cannot be null
```

Mas não vejo no seu código você declarando essa coluna com esse nome

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
   return id;
}
```

E por ser informado que essa coluna existe no seu banco de dados acredito que em algum momento você tenha feito isso:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "pais_id")
public Long getId() {
   return id;
}
```

Minha dica é, verifica se na sua tabela tem uma coluna chamada `id` e uma chamada `pais_id`, muito provável que tenha, então, você deleta essa tabela e gera novamente.

Se possível posta a tabela gerada também.
Editando conforme comentário. Na sua classe Pais faça a seguinte alteração:

```
 ...   
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "pais_id")
  public Long getId() {
  return id;
}
    ...
```

E na sua classe Estado, você faz o seguinte:

```
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais_id", nullable = false)
public Pais getPais() {
   return pais;
}
...
```

Edita seu método salvar do Bean

```
public void salvar() {
  this.estado = cadastroEstadoService.salvar(estado); //tira o this de estado
  limpar();
  FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Estado salvo com sucesso.");
```

Comment: Oi Edjane, mas o país está salvando. O que não está salvando é  o valor do pais_id na tabela estado, na relação @ManyToOne.

Comment: O que não entendo é onde você esta declarando que o nome da coluna na tabela é pais_id, na verdade nunca gerei uma tabela no hibernate sem declarar o nome da coluna id, mas vou editar a questão com o que acho que você pode fazer para corrigir esse problema.

Comment: Oi Edjane, eu criei a tabela novamente usando o "create". Na tabela país ele cria o id, nome, sigla. E na tabela estado, cria id, nome, sigla e pais_id. Então, acho que não é o problema da propriedade "name", pois caso contrário não criaria nem a tabela corretamente. O que achas?

Comment: Sim, pelo que você colocou ele criou a tabela de forma correta, você fez as alterações que falei? Tirou o this de salvar(estado)? Uma dica, você esta trabalhando com frameworks e nesse "mundo" as coisas tem que ser bem "casadas", faz as alterações, pois não vi outros problemas no seu código a não ser esses que falei.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema, possivelmente, está aqui:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
public Pais getPais() {
     return pais;
}
```

A coluna `pais_id` não é referenciada em nenhum momento no seu mapeamento, logo ela não é mapeada e, por consequência, não preenchida na hora da gravação dos dados. Como ela tem uma *constraint* de não poder ser nula, o erro ocorre.

Experiment acrescentar `name = "pais_id"` na anotação de `@JoinColumn` e veja se o erro deixa de acontecer.

Comment: Vou tentar mas acredito que o default name do @jointcolumn é o nome do objeto acrescido de _id. Neste caso, como não coloquei nada, ele está usando o name pais_id.